# How to map public port to private port in azure Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, port, azure-virtual-machine

I am using Azure virtual machine to host a ***TCP Server***  application. I created a public port[***80***] and private port [***8000***] in azure virtual machine. How can I connect my external ***TCP Client*** application to TCP Server Application running in azure virtual machine?

Is it done by mapping public port 80 to private port 8000; and run my server on private port?
If so how to map?

Answer (score 1):

You can map ports on Windows Azure Virtual machines in the portal.

Click on the virtual machine in the portal and switch to the `ENDPOINTS` tab, click `+ Add` and follow the 2 step wizard adding a public and private port to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did the same which you said. But my socket client can not make any connection to public port. what can be the problem? I have defined the inbound rule for private port also.

Answer (score 1):

You'll also need to create a rule in your firewall to accept incoming connections on port 8000.